# Nginx multiple root for location

Tags: nginx, location, root

I have a location defined like this.

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|flv|mp4|mov|avi|wmv|m4v|mkv|ico|css|js|txt|html|htm)$ {
    root /path/to/static/files/;
}
```

If I request `/events.js` which is in `/path/to/static/files/` it works fine.

But if I request `/func.js` which is in `/other/path/to/static/files/` it won't find it.

So what I need is two locations from which the static files can be found. There aren't any other differences between the two requests, they are identical from same app the only difference is the physical location of the files. Also I don't know the names of the files they are completely random.

### Solution

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|flv|mp4|mov|avi|wmv|m4v|mkv|ico|css|js|txt|html|htm)$ {
    root /;
    try_files /path/to/static/files/$uri /other/path/to/static/files/$uri /;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like the following:

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|flv|mp4|mov|avi|wmv|m4v|mkv|ico|css|js|txt|html|htm)$ {
  root /;
  try_files /path/to/static/files/$uri /other/path/to/static/files/$uri;
}
```

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files for how that works